# How to get signin tenant while setting security in azure api management using azure active directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I need Signin Tenant for setting azure active directory in API management services.

I tried already tried the azure public domain i.e. xxx.onmicrosoft.com but it's not working using this.

No code as it's with the configuration on azure portal.

While clicking on Add button
Could not create identity provider 
One or more fields contain incorrect values:
No Azure Active Directory tenant specified for provider.

Answer (score 0):

Signin tenant is optional, but "Allowed tenants" are not, so you must specify those, most likely as xxx.onmicrosoft.com.